# Does django staticfiles skip the middleware?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm running a django 1.4.1 app.

I didn't realize that just including `django.contrib.staticfiles` into `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings is enough to get static files served while `settings.DEBUG` is True, i.e., you don't have to manually add anything to your urls file.

I also noticed that this bypasses the django middleware. Does anyone know how or why this happens?

---

I just created a blank new project, my views.py:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    html = '<html><body>Logo: <img src="/static/logo.gif"></body></html>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My urls.py:

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'testapp.views.index', name='home'),
)
```

My settings.py has specified a directory to look for static files, and it also has this added:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'testapp.middleware.TestMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Using this middleware:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
class TestMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        print("[REQUEST]", request.path)
```

And when I make a request, this gets printed out:

```
[REQUEST] /
[18/Jan/2013 15:30:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 60
[18/Jan/2013 15:30:27] "GET /static/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2190
[REQUEST] /favicon.ico
```

Is it something to do with how the test server starts up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just figured this out after posting…

If you're using `django-admin.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver`, then it does some extra magic to add a staticfiles handler that your regular middleware can't touch.

You can disable this by running `django-admin.py runserver --nostatic` — see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---nostatic)

And when you do `--nostatic` it will fall back to the urls in your app, such as if you include staticfiles_urls() directly with:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

then your middleware will run for those urls (and of course all your others).

Answer (score 1):

Found this issue when trying to modify request.path with middleware.

Discovered urls resolve against `request.path_info` not `request.path`